# Expose additional port on Kafka Connect for thread listener port

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka Connect and have an independent thread started in my connector plugin that is listening on a port (say "9090").  I want to use this port to allow applications (external to the kafka environment) to communicate with my connector plugin.

I am running Kafka Connect (and the kafka environment) in docker-compose.

Question: how can the port be exposed in docker compose so that external apps can reach my connector plugin thread listener port?

Here is what I have come up with so far, but it seems odd that I would need to expose an external port on a kafka connect component.  Is this a sound practice or is there a better way to allow apps to communicate with my connect plugin thread listener port?

Below is a segment of my docker-compose file that shows how I expose port "9090" on connect:

```
:
:
:
      connect:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.2.0
        hostname: connect
        container_name: connect
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
          - kafka
        ports:
          - 8083:8083
          - 9090:9090
        environment:
          CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
          CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
          CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
:
:
:
```

Comment: Connect just runs a Jetty server. You're opening a new port, so what's wrong with this? Keep in mind that each Connect task cannot open the same port on the same host, so you would be limited to `tasks.max=1`

Comment: @OneCriketeer Correct - to handle volumes I would increase "tasks.max" and add a range of ports (same number as tasks.max) that I would need to listen to.

Comment: I assume you'd loop through the ports to find the next open one? But that might be an issue with task rebalancing... In any case, the [Syslog connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-syslog/current/syslog_source_connector_config.html) for example, basically requires the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below is very similar to what I had expected, and verified by @OneCricketeer, but I added a range of ports (below, 9090-9094) to the connect docker-compose configuration.  I would also make the "listener" thread component listen on a range of ports equal to the number of tasks.max (in the example below, it would be 5).

```
:
:
:
      connect:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.2.0
        hostname: connect
        container_name: connect
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
          - kafka
        ports:
          - 8083:8083
          - 9090-9094:9090-9094
        environment:
          CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
          CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
          CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
:
:
:
```

Comment: Good catch - I will update the solution